# Carbon and dilute sulfuric acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I have to distinguish between copper oxide and carbon. I thought of dilute sulfuric acid because it forms copper sulfate with copper oxide. But I don't know how carbon reacts with dilute sulfuric acid. I know how carbon reacts with *concentrated* sulfuric acid but dilute?

Comment: see this:-http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42880/what-is-the-product-of-the-reaction-of-carbon-with-sulfuric-acid/50763#50763

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sulfuric acid is  unreactive with carbon- indeed only hot concentrated sulfuric acid reacts with carbon to produce carbon dioxide.

Comment: Then how can i distinguish between copper oxide and carbon?