# What is the product of the reaction of carbon with sulfuric acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

I don't know if $\ce{C}$ or $\ce{CuO}$ react with $\ce{H2SO4}$. Some sources say that: 
 $$\ce{C + H2SO4 -> CO2 ^ + 2SO2 ^ + 2 H2O}$$
(It seems to be similar to $\ce{Cu}$ reactions with $\ce{H2SO4}$).
Is the reaction possible? If the answer is yes, in what conditions does the reaction take place?

And I was pretty sure that $\ce{CuO + H2SO4 -> CuSO4 v + H2O}$

But my chemistry book says that none of the reactions is possible.
I'm little bit confused, some help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carbon reacts with sulfuric acid to produce carbon dioxide and sulfur dioxide gas along with water. Sulfuric acid should be a concentrated, heated solution.

$$\ce{C + 2H2SO4 ->[\Delta] CO2 + 2SO2 + 2H2O}$$

More insight about this reaction can be found [here](https://web.anl.gov/PCS/acsfuel/preprint%20archive/Files/03_2_BOSTON_04-59_0169.pdf).

Copper(II) oxide, a black solid, and dilute sulfuric acid react to produce copper(II) sulfate, giving a characteristic blue colour to the solution. From this solution, blue copper(II) sulfate pentahydrate crystals may be obtained if desired.

$$\ce{CuO + H2SO4⟶CuSO4↓+H2O}$$

It is a general "insoluble metal oxide is reacted with a dilute acid to form a soluble salt" type of reaction. It is a standard class experiment.

More insight about this reaction can be found [here](http://www.rsc.org/learn-chemistry/resource/res00001917/reacting-copper-ii-oxide-with-sulfuric-acid?cmpid=CMP00006703).